# Changing Header Image Height

Tags: css

I can't make the header image's height bigger. I found some CSS that made the container height bigger. But every time I change the photo out, it is still the original `height: 75px;`.

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  height:200px; 
  float:left;
  margin-top:2px;
}
```

[thml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcioY.png)

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CogFH.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the `html` part of your code. Also, there's a difference to adjusting the `div`/container height and adjusting the height of the `img` itself. And in the case of you declaring a background-image in your CSS, then there'd be `background-size` property to consider.

Comment: like @YongPin mentioned, you need to style the image's height, to make it follow the container's height, try give the image a height: 100%

Comment: @YongPin To show the html would I just inspect that area and share it?

Comment: @mok_ku make the height in the code below 100%

    .container {
  width:100%;
  height:200px; 
  float:left;
  margin-top:2px;
}

Comment: @Cody that works as well, as long as you show the `div` or whatever container/tag you used the `.container` class to.

Comment: @YongPin I added screenshots to the post

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot i did not see any image element. If you want the image to to follow have a fixed height, you can set a height to the image itself, but if you want the image to follow the container's height, then u need to give a height to the **direct container** of the image, at the same time give a height to the image, 100% if you want the image to follow the height of the container.

From the code you provided. your `.container` has a height of 200px. If the image is inside this container, and you wish to make the image exactly 200px as the `.container`, then you need to add `.container img{height:100%}` to the image.

Answer (score -1):

Try this CSS rule:

```
header {
    min-height: 50% !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There should be something below the image that is blocking your height.
Make sure to check from the inspect element

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).